# Reading from and writing to process using subprocess

Tags: python, io, subprocess

I have been (unsuccessfully) trying to use Python's `subprocess` module to interact with an executable program. The program is a very simple command line based script.

It basically just acts in the following way: prompt user with text, wait for numeric input, prompt with more text, wait for next input, etc.

So I set up the subprocess like so

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen('filename.exe', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

Then I get the first prompt

```
print p.stdout.readline()
```

Properly returns

> Enter some value blah blah

Great! Then I try to enter the desired value

```
p.stdin.write('10.0')
```

It then completely hangs. I can try grabbing the next prompt

```
print p.stdout.readline()
```

but it still hangs no matter what.

What is the proper way to do this one line read/write business? I must be messing up the `write` line I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably forgetting to output a newline:

```
p.stdin.write('10.0\n')
```

What happens is that your subprocess is receiving the data, but waiting for more input, until it finds a newline. If you wait for output from the process in this state, you deadlock the system.

Comment: @Cyber: don't feel stupid. It is very easy to deadlock if you use blocking `p.stdin/p.stdout` directly. `\n` might not be enough; you might need `os.linesep` instead or you might need `p.stdin.flush()`. Set `bufsize` for `Popen` explicitely. It has different defaults on different Python versions. Also, how do you know that `p.stdout.readline()` is enough. What if the answer is two lines? Ideally,  use `p.communicate(input)` if you can i.e., when the input doesn't depend on the output. Also the subprocess may write outside of stdout/stderr e.g., directly to a terminal. You could use `pexpect`.